# Execute a method after a delay?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing an MVC 4 windows service that receives messages, analyzes them and sends a response.  In certain cases I want the response to be delayed by a few minutes.  I understand how to use the `System.Threading.Timer` to execute a method after a delay, but I think that any reference to the timer object would be gone when the processing method ends, allowing the timer to be garbage collected, right?

I've pretty much decided I need to keep a static list of timers somewhere, adding a reference when the timer is created and removing it (and call Timer.Dispose()) when the callback method is called.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Do I read this correct `MVC 4 windows service`?

Comment: Yep, as recommended by my mentor.  Like I said, I'm a n00b.  :)

Comment: My knowledge is improving (if not my judgement), it's actually a Web API Windows Service.

Comment: +1 for coming back to this post after such a long time and updating us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should read Phil Haack's article, [*The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET*](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Then assuming you really want to do this, have the web application start a timer in the `global.asax` method `Application_Start()` such that it will fire on the frequency that you want. That timer should be static property of the application itself and the event handler that gets invoked should likewise be a static method of the application.

You'll also need a priority queue of items needed processing where each item is timestamped with its due date/time and the priority is the due date/time. Don't forget to synchronize access to the queue.

To queue something up for later delivery, your web method should add an item to the queue.

Each time the event handler fires, it peeks at the head of the queue for an item that need processing. If one is found, it removes it, processes it and repeats until its window has expired, the queue is empty or the head of the queue is not yet due.

Comment: First, thank you for spending so much time on an answer.  You obviously have a deep knowledge of the platform.  However, I don't have a requirement for a recurring task, just a single shot delayed action.  You are certainly correct that a periodically serviced priority queue would solve my problem, but I'm a lazy b****rd and I'm looking for something simple and tailored to my specific problem. (I reserve the right to amend this response after I actually ready your linked article.)

Comment: Just read the article, thanks again!  It's always nice when a blogger infuses his diatribes with a sense of humor!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Thread.Sleep()` method.

```
// Wait 5 seconds ...
Thread.Sleep(5000);

// Execute delayed code here.
```

Comment: Very simple, just like I'd requested!  I don't expect high traffic, but I would still be worried about tying up a thread.  The required delay is a random value between n and m minutes, where n > 1 and m < 10, so could still be a problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

A proper solution would be not to let your client wait for minutes while the server sends a response. technically it could trigger a time-out at the client end, let the calls be asynchronous and do what ever that you are doing at the server end and have a flag to let the client know that its done, the client can poll your service periodically (every 30 secs maybe) to find-out if the work is ready and complete.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but in this case the request and response are SMS messages at the client end, so no timeout concern.  I do reply to the SMS forwarder immediately.